# Android ListView item click event listener to reference current activity delegate method

Tags: android, ios, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying out Android development a bit and hope this hasn't been asked before, as I'm not aware of the correct Android terminology for my question.

I mainly do iOS programming. What I'm basically trying to do is create a UITableView that has a tap event on each cell and the console should just say something like "fruit" but I am trying to do this using Android.

So far, I have this for the `onItemClickEventListener`:

```
public class MainViewController extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view_controller);

        // Get list view from xml
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Define data source to show in list view
        String[] items = new String[] {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Watermelon",
                "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Watermelon",
                "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Watermelon",
                "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Watermelon",
                "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Watermelon"};

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Need to use Adapters to send data to list view
        //
        // First parameter: Context
        // Second parameter: Layout for the row
        // Third parameter: ID of the TextView to which data is written
        // Forth parameter: array of data
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                android.util.Log.i("Console Output: ", "Fruits!");



            }
        });

        ...
```

This works but I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
// psuedocode
void onCreate()
{
    ...

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // this doesn't work when I tried it, said something about
    // cannot apply the onItemClick method on my ViewController
    // and can only be applied on AdapterViews
    //
    // I thought View Controllers are meant to handle these kind of
    // thing not Views ?
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(MainViewController.this);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// override the delegate method here instead of doing it 
// inline in the onCreate() method above
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    android.util.Log.i("Console Output: ", "Fruits!");

});
```

I'm not sure if it's a good practice to add the on click listener method inline, I'm trying to avoid crazy blocks of indentation.

Am I making any sense ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anonymous method (the former one you used) is harder for debugging

You should implement the OnItemClickListener in your Activity OR create a private class which implements the OnItemClickListener to handle the clicks

Comment: That's what I did Patrick, I have an Activity called `MainViewController` and I passed it in `listView.setOnItemClickListener(MainViewController.this);` but it says I cannot apply the setOnItemClickListener() to MainViewController.

Comment: did you declare "public class MainViewController extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener"?

Comment: No I didn't know I have to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as by implementing `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in Activity:

```
public class MainViewController extends ActionBarActivity 
implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
....
}
```

and instead of implemeting `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in Activity you can add listner to ListView as:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listviewItemClick=
                                   new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                                      View view, int position, long id) {


            }
        });
```

In onCreate method :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(listviewItemClick);
```

Comment: Patrick's answer is more closer to what I want but your answer was also one of my other question which I wanted to know. Is there any advantages of doing it this way by creating a clickEvent variable that stores the onItemClick() method instead of simply implementing the onItemClick() method and passing in MainViewController.this ?